# Как открыть фрагмент из View

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

```
public class PubItemView extends RelativeLayout{
.....
public PubItemView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public PubItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }
....
@OnClick(R.id.buttonReport) public void openReport() {
        ReportDialogFrg fr = new ReportDialogFrg();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ReportDialogFrg.PUBLICATION_KEY, pub);
        fr.setArguments(args);
        fr.show((NearestFrg)getActivity().getFragmentManager(), null);//тут проблема 
    }
}
```

Если бы я был в фрагменте то

```
fr.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), null); //для фрагмента работает
```

Как вызвать фрагмент fr из PubItemView ?

Comment: А какая ошибка-то?... Контекст не получить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо получить контекст, скастовать его к активити и из него получить FragmentManager как-то так:

```
fr.show(((ИМЯ_КЛАССА_АКТИВИТИ_В_КОЕМ_НАХОДИТСЯ_VIEW)getContext()).getFragmentManager(), null);
```